# SwiperJs - TypeError Type '{ "--swiper-pagination-color": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, next.js, swiper.js

I'm using ([Swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper)) in NextJS and I'm trying to change the styling of the pagination and navigation, without overriding the styles in global styles. To my knowledge, It cannot be done in module CSS, So I resorted to using inline CSS with Swiper Component [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72922527/13839892).

But it throws type error -

```
Type '{ "--swiper-pagination-color": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"--swiper-pagination-color"' does not exist in type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1863, 9): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps'
```

Even Swiper's own [Demos](https://swiperjs.com/demos#thumbs-gallery-loop) which links to the [code sandbox (line 23)](https://codesandbox.io/s/pfhz3h?file=/src/App.jsx) show this way of exact way of styling the Pagination and Navigation. As a typescript newbie I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Here is the Swiper Component that I'm using. -

```
             <Swiper
              loop={true}
              spaceBetween={10}
              slidesPerView={1}
              navigation={true}
              style={{
                "--swiper-pagination-color": "#fff",
              }}
              thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null }}
              modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
            >
              {imgs?.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <SwiperSlide key={index} className={styles.carouselImageDivUpper}>
                    <TransformWrapper>
                      <TransformComponent>
                        <img className={styles.carouselImage} src={item?.s3UrlLink} />
                      </TransformComponent>
                    </TransformWrapper>
                  </SwiperSlide>
                );
              })}
            </Swiper>
```

Comment: What if you move the custom property declaration to the parent DOM node(s) of `<Swiper>`, since CSS properties cascade down the DOM tree and are inheritable. If you're using TypeScript, consider manually casting the object you're passing into the `style` attribute to `React.CSSProperties`, i.e. `style={{ ... } as React.CSSProperties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terry's comment contains the answer to your question, so this is how it's implemented in code:

```
<Swiper
          loop={true}
          spaceBetween={10}
          slidesPerView={1}
          navigation={true}
          style={{
            "--swiper-pagination-color": "#fff",
          } as CSSProperties}
          thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null }}
          modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
        >
          {imgs?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <SwiperSlide key={index} className={styles.carouselImageDivUpper}>
                <TransformWrapper>
                  <TransformComponent>
                    <img className={styles.carouselImage} src={item?.s3UrlLink} />
                  </TransformComponent>
                </TransformWrapper>
              </SwiperSlide>
            );
          })}
        </Swiper>
```